# Is "WHERE (subquery) IN (subquery)" possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, relational-division

We need to select the Tests that only use the tags connected to Machine.

- Tags are many to many to Tests. (TagTest associative table)
- Tags are many to many to Machines. (TagMachine associative table)

Examples:

- If a Test has tags [A,B,C] and Machine has [A,B,D] the test should not be chosen because its tags are not a subset of Machine's tags.
- If a Test has tags [A,B] and Machine has [A,B,D] the test should be included.
- If a Test has no tags it should always be included.

Something like this construct should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test te
WHERE 
    (SELECT tt.tagId
    FROM TagTest tt 
    WHERE tt.testId = te.Id)
 IN
    (SELECT tm.tagId
    FROM TagMachine tm
    WHERE tm.machineId = 123)
```

However is this kind of query possible? If not, how is it possible to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Check the [`ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ALL) operator.

Comment: @zerkms Doesn't the ALL operator also require the left value to be a scalar?

Comment: You're right, it's irrelevant, I just woke up and not ready to think efficiently yet. Sorry.

Comment: *please* add your table definitions+some testdata to the question. You have 4 tables: 2 domain tables +2 bridge-tables?

Comment: @wildplasser It is more of a theoretical question, so I guess you can assume that there only are these 4 tables.

Comment: But now,5-10 people are attempting to reinvent your table structures. You could help them. BTWL I added the `relational division` tag, you could find some inspiration in the *related* section to the right of this comment. -->>VV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IN()` can't do this by itself. You can make two CTE's and JOIN them together, but it's still a bit tricky.

Instead, let's turn the problem around. Instead of looking for records that match *all* good tags, we can look for records that are *missing any one required tag*. From the first example in the question (`[A,B,C]` vs `[A,B,D]`), we're looking for the `TestTag` records with the `C` tag. Once we have this information, we can use it in a subquery to exclude all `Test` records with an `Id` that appeared in those results.

So the first thing to do is use an exclusion join to find `TestTag` results where the corresponding `TagMachine` record is missing:

```
SELECT tt.testId, tt.tagId
FROM TestTag tt 
LEFT JOIN TagMachine tm ON tm.machineId = 123 AND tm.tagId = tt.tagId
WHERE tm.tagId IS NULL
```

The presence of any `testId` in the results of the above query makes the `Test` with that `Id` *ineligible*... but we do want *all other* `Test` records. So now just limit this to `DISTINCT testId` and use it as a subquery in any of an exclusion join, NOT IN(), or NOT EXISTS(). Take your pick:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tests
WHERE Id NOT IN (
     --identify tests hat are missing at least one tag
     SELECT DISTINCT tt.testId 
     FROM TestTag tt 
     LEFT JOIN TagMachine tm ON tm.machineId = 123 AND tm.tagId = tt.tagId
     WHERE tm.tagId IS NULL)
```

Comment: Really nice solution! Without using any sql dialect specific contructs.

Answer (score 4):

This query is possible if the first returns a scalar value (that is a single row).  So, what you want to do is not possible using just `IN`.  One Postres'y way to handle this uses arrays

```
WHERE (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(tt.tagId)
       FROM TagTest tt 
       WHERE tt.testId = te.Id
      ) <@
      (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(tm.tagId)
       FROM TagMachine tm
       WHERE tm.machineId = 123
      )
```